# How to add number of days to a timestamp?

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-cloud-functions

I had a start date timestamp and a duration (number of days), I need to get end date, I'm tired this code by gives my a wrong end date timestamp

```
exports.terminateStoreAd = functions.https.onRequest(async(req, res) => {
        try {
            const snapshot =await admin.database().ref("StoreAds").once("value");
            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                snapshot.forEach(snapData => {
                    if (snapData.exists()) {
                        const endDate=new Date(snapData.val().startDate).getTime()+(snapData.val().duration*24*60*60*1000);
                        res.send(""+endDate);
                    }
                });
                res.send("done")
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("terminateStoreAd error :" + error.message); 
        }
    });
```

my start date is : 1559449773

duration : 5

end date: 1991449773  :(

thanks in advance.

Comment: What should the end date be instead? Are you certain you're getting the expected value from duration?

Comment: @Doug Stevenson expected value from duration was wrong and after 2 days of searching ,i found  the equation was wrong and the right one is:
 const endDate=childSnapshot.val().startDate + childSnapshot.val().duration  * 86400;

Answer (score 0):

Given start date of 2019-05-01 then 5 days later is simple matter of creating a new date using the parameterized version.

Note the month is zero indexed so May, the 5th month is index 4.  Since I want 5 days past May 1st I use `1+5` as the day:

```js
const startDate = new Date(2019, 4, 1);
const endDate = new Date(startDate.getFullYear(), startDate.getMonth(), startDate.getDate()+5);

console.log(`Start Date: ${startDate}, End Date: ${endDate}`);
console.log(`Start Date: ${startDate.valueOf()}, End Date: ${endDate.valueOf()}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const endDate = snapData.val().startDate + snapData.val().duration*24*60*60*1000;
```

is enough to get the required date in milliseconds (if `startDate` is in milliseconds)

Else if `startDate` is a Date string,

```
const endDate = (new Date(snapData.val().startDate)).getTime() + snapData.val().duration*24*60*60*1000;
```

Assuming you require `endDate` in milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

**finally i got the solution**

```
exports.terminateStoreAd = functions.https.onRequest(async(req, res) => {
try {
    const snapshot =await admin.database().ref("StoreAds").once("value");
    const promises = [];
    if (snapshot.exists()) {
        snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
            const endDate=childSnapshot.val().startDate + childSnapshot.val().duration  * 86400;
            const today=Math.round(new Date().getTime()/1000);
            if (endDate <= today) {
                promises.push(
                    admin.database().ref("StoreAdsHistory").child(childSnapshot.key).set(childSnapshot.val()),
                    childSnapshot.ref.remove(),
                    res.send()
                );
            }
        });
       } 
       await Promise.all(promises);
    }catch (error) {

}
```

});